# MySQL - Return from a string the leftmost characters from 2 different characters

Tags: mysql, string, split

I have a database with some codes seperated by / or -, I want to show the left side only, this is an example of the data:

```
45/84
12/753
68-53
15742-845
2/556
```

So, i want to get this:

```
45
12
68
15742
2
```

I tried using LEFT(), but this search for 1 character only, and returns a warning if the character is not found, this is what LEFT(field,'/') returns.

```
45
12
(WARNING)
(WARNING)
2
```

So, what about a REGEXP?
an IF?
any way to ignore from the first non numeric character?

I dont' have more ideas...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-', 1), '/', 1)
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f17c9/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this statement. Replace the string '15742/845' with your fieldname

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( REPLACE('15742/845','/','-'), '-', 1)
```